enable intellij to link another ftl file on click
I use intellij Ultimate .
consider this ftl file :

intellij perfectly links the import and whenever I click on getBannerOrg() it takes me to the featureGetter.ftl file's getBannerOrg() method.
I do not intend to provide <#import '/common/featureGetter.ftl' as feature> on every ftl file. instead, I provide that import as a global which imports it to all my ftl files.

problem: no since it does not hold reference to feature variable intellij would not identify feature. is there any way i could statically supply intellij with some configuration that for this variable link this ftl file ? I refered this link https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/template-data-languages.html but unable to come up with any working solution. appreciate any help .
